SQL Server query works but not when scheduled
I'm working on a query to generate a report for some users. The report runs in a third party program which is how the users interact with the database, and they will run the report through this program's GUI (The program is Trimble/3LOG LIMS, but I would be surprised if many people had heard of it).
The query works as expected both in SSMS and within the reporting application, but the issue arises when I try to schedule the report to run automatically. I know this is really more of a problem with the LIMS application, but it's throwing a SQL error, so I suspect it might be solvable by structuring the query differently.
The error I'm getting is

Must declare the scalar variable

My best guess is that the app runs the scheduled query in batches in some way, and that the variable declaration is then out of scope of where I'm trying to use it? I know this is a lot of guesswork without knowing how the program works, but I at least want to rule out that it's not a FireDAC or ODBC issue or something like that.
I have tried hardcoding the values rather than using variables, but I get other errors then that I suspect might be related, so if I can solve this issue, I think it would lead to me figuring out the others.
The query:
DECLARE @L_LB_TO_TON DECIMAL(5,4) = 0.0005,
        @L_KG_TO_TON DECIMAL(9,8) = 0.00110231

SELECT
    l.other_values,
    v.other_values,
    t.other_values,
    (CASE 
         WHEN l.scale_uom = 'LB' 
             THEN CAST(@L_LB_TO_TON * CAST(l.net AS BIGINT) AS DECIMAL(12,4))
         WHEN l.scale_uom = 'KG'
             THEN CAST(@L_KG_TO_TON * CAST(l.net AS BIGINT) AS DECIMAL(12,4))
         ELSE NULL
     END) AS net_tons
FROM
    table l
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 c ON c.value = l.value
LEFT JOIN 
    table3 v ON v.value = c.value
LEFT JOIN 
    table4 wl ON wl.value = l.value 
              AND wl.value2 = l.value2
LEFT JOIN 
    table5 t ON t.value = l.trip_value
WHERE 
    stuff_is_true
ORDER BY
    something

Specific error:

[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Must declare the scalar variable "@L_LB_TO_TON"

I've tried selecting the values rather than using the variables, and I've tried selecting them in a WITH clause before the SELECT statement, but the former gives an error of missing a closing */ when all comments are closed properly, and the latter just gives an error of "Incorrect syntax near WITH." I also tried a semicolon before WITH.
Again, this will probably end up being something specific to how LIMS handles this kind of query when automated, but I'm hoping that maybe there is something else I can try.

Thanks! Just an error when creating the post though.

Start a wireshark trace on the tds protocol and enjoy the actual queries this application generates, it should probably help you figure out the issue

Some programs attempt to implement their own T-SQL parsers and don't always get it right. This seems to be the problem here given that it doesn't understand that CTEs start with the WITH keyword either. Have you simply tried to remove the scalar variable definitions for @L_LB_TO_TON and @L_KG_TO_TON and replace their usages with the literal values 0.0005 and 0.00110231?

I'm going to hazard a guess that it's splitting up the script into separate batches. Variables only apply to a single batch and scope.

Is you program able to call stored procedures? If it is you could try putting the query in a stored procedure and just calling the procedure from the program.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I believe the correct answer, as many guessed, was the batching of the query, as it worked in the same program under other circumstances. I ended up finding something in the third party program that seemed to fix the issue, so it wasn't a SQL solution to the problem after all.
